# For a finite character set $\Sigma$, what would be a formal proof that $\Sigma^{+} = \Sigma^{*}\Sigma$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computer-science

Let there be a finite character set $\Sigma$, as in computer science convention. $\Sigma^{*}$ is defined as in Kleene star notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) with $\Sigma^{+}$ defined as Kleene plus of $\Sigma$.

Now proving $\Sigma^{+} = \Sigma^{*}\Sigma = \{ab | a \in \Sigma^{*} \wedge b \in \Sigma \}$. I know that I can prove by saying because all strings in $\Sigma^{*}$ contain finite characters, adding another character to right does not change finiteness of character, and because $\Sigma^{*}$ contains an empty character, $\Sigma^{+} = \Sigma^{*}\Sigma$. However, I cannot find a formal way of proving this.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Sorry, those aren't definitions, those are names.

Comment: Brian provided a nice answer to your question, but your "informal" proof looks fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the definitions in the Wikipedia article to which you linked, you have

$$\begin{align*}
\Sigma^+&=\bigcup_{k\ge 1}\Sigma_k\\
&=\bigcup_{k\ge 0}\Sigma_{k+1}\\
&=\bigcup_{k\ge 0}\left(\Sigma_k\Sigma\right)\\
&=\left(\bigcup_{k\ge 0}\Sigma_k\right)\Sigma\\
&=\Sigma^*\Sigma\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Any reason why you use $\Sigma_k$ instead of the standard $\Sigma^k$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Yes: I was deliberately following the notation used in the definition in the cited article.